# Arduino specific community

Tags: discussion

There is a new proposal for a new [Arduino related SE community](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/49538/arduino). Do you think it is helpful to redirect some questions to this community? Or should Arduino related topics stay at EE?

Comment: Are you asking if we will send our arduino questions to Arduino.SE or opposite, you sending us the EE questions you get? Arduino questions are explicitly on-topic here and the migrating poor questions, the only ones we close, goes against migrations. Beysides that that, I am very very hesitant to any early beta site. We dont want to impact a community by sending our crap that way early.

Comment: @Kortuk: Arduino shouldn't be specifically spelled out in the site description. Perhaps that is causing the recent infestation of badly written arduino-related questions? If it's about real electronics it's welcome here, even if someone is using a arduino. However, the fact that a arduino is envolved actually makes it *less* likely it is a good question for here. Anyway, why should arduino be so special to be called out specifically? If you're going to get that specific, PIC questions would be more likely on topic (except for the "chipkit" arduino knockoff, of course).

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate thread.  The possible kinds of interplay between the proposed Arduino.SE and EE.SE have been recenly discussed at some length [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/2656/7036).  I can only add that I look forward to Arduino.SE coming online.

Comment: @OlinLathrop our site formed that way. Hardware and electronics all the way down to arduino. It was specifically noted before as it specified sort of a limit. We have bad questions of all kinds, i think it is just easier to notice those related to arduino. Probably impacted by our association with stackoverflow.

Comment: I have closed this as the absence of an arduino site makes the question invalid at this point.

Answer (score 7):

**Every question that is on topic here should stay here.** No arguments, I just feel that's right.

You might try getting closed as off topic questions reopened and then migrated to Arduino, but I don't think that's useful. Those questions most of the time show a lack of research, are badly worded or are a very small coding problem that isn't really that valuable that you would want it on the Arduino Beta.

Answer (score 3):

There are certainly questions that pop up here on occasion that would be a better fit on the Arduino site. For example, "What shield should I use for xxxx?" or anything involving the Arduino libraries. We have an active Arduino base here, but I would rather see questions like those go away, they really have nothing to do electronic design.

Comment: Those are shopping questions and are off topic here anyway, so if Arduino.SE wants them, let's migrate those indeed!

Answer (score -1):

No.  The good ones we answer and the bad ones we tar and feather, run out of town, downvote to oblivion, and eventually close.  You don't want the crappy ones either.